# Virtualbox- Can't set up 2nd adapter to network, even though VM is powered off

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to add a 2nd adapter to my VM so that I can ping to my VM from another computer, but so far I've been unsuccessful.  The specific problem I am having is that, when I click "Enable Network Adapter" under the "Adapter 2" tab, and I select "Host-only Adapter next to the "Attached to:" dropdown, I am not given any options besides "Not selected" in the "Name" dropdown.

I saw [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/732999/virtualbox-cant-add-2nd-adapter-to-network-for-vm), but my VM was already off when I tried to add the new adapter.

UPDATE: See screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before being able to select a host-only network, you need to create one:

1. from the CLI,

   `VBoxManage hostonlyif create`
2. from the GUI, `File` -> `Preferences` -> `Network` -> `Host-only network` -> `(+)Add host-only network`